# Sort My class by two values

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, sorting

I have a class `MyLines` with 2 properties, `StartPoint` and `EndPoint`.

I also have a `List(Of MyLines)`

```
Dim ListOfLines As New List(Of MyLines)
```

In theory all `MyLines` will match at one end as a "Series of lines" (If that makes sense)
I want to do 3 operations on this list.

**First operation:**
If any `MyLines.EndPoint` is equal to any other `MyLines.Endpoint` it should execute `SwapEnds` to make sure all the data is in order. Because the data should be SP, EP, SP, EP, SP, EP......

**Second Operation:**
Which ever `MyLines.Startpoint` has no match to any other `MyLines.EndPoint` this `MyLines` Should be the first of the new list

**Third Operation:**
I then want to sort the remaining `MyLines` so the `MyLines.EndPoint` of each `MyLines` matches the `MyLines.StartPoint` of the next `MyLines`.

As the data can be input in the incorrect order I (have created a `SwapEnd` method but I am not sure how to check for this)

Looking for ideas. Ill take answers in VB.net or C#
Thanks in advance. :)

```
Public Class MyLines
Implements IComparable(Of MyLines)

Private m_StartPoint As Point3d
Private m_EndPoint As Point3d

Public Sub New(ByVal StartPoint As Point3d, ByVal EndPoint As Point3d)
    m_StartPoint = StartPoint
    m_EndPoint = EndPoint
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property StartPoint() As Point3d
    Get
        Return m_StartPoint
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property EndPoint() As Point3d
    Get
        Return m_EndPoint
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub SwapEnd()

    Dim OldValue As Point3d = New Point3d(m_StartPoint)
    m_StartPoint = New Point3d(m_EndPoint)
    m_EndPoint = New Point3d(OldValue)
    Debug.Print("Swapped")
End Sub

Public Function CompareTo(other As MyLines) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of MyLines).CompareTo
    Return EndPoint.IsEqualTo(other.StartPoint, New Tol(0.0001, 0.0001))
End Function
```

Comment: What happens when three lines intersect at the same point?  Normally this is done by having list of points with list of neighbors points which are the lines that connect the points.  You swap doesn't make a lot of sense since a straight line is symmetrical and you will get exactly the same results as you started with.

Comment: Lines will only ever intersect at either end with a different line.  Think of this as one long line with vertices.

Comment: Can the path loop back on its self or is always progressive in one direction?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list `open` of line segments that still have to be ordered and a list `ordered` of ordered segments. The former will be the initial list of line segments, the latter will start to be empty. Then start with any line segment and try to find its continuation in both directions:

```vb
//Pseudo code
Move first entry from open to ordered
Dim foundNext As Boolean
Do 'Forward direction
    foundNext = False
    For Each segment in open
        If open.Last().EndPoint = segment.StartPoint
            move segment from open to end of ordered
            FoundNext = True
            Continue While
        Else If open.Last().EndPoint = segment.EndPoint
            segment.Swap()
            move segment from open to end of ordered
            FoundNext = True
            Continue While
        End If
     Next
While foundNext
Do 'Backward direction
    foundNext = False
    For Each segment in open
        If open.First().StartPoint = segment.EndPoint
            move segment from open to beginning of ordered
            FoundNext = True
            Continue While
        Else If open.Last().StartPoint = segment.StartPoint
            segment.Swap()
            move segment from open to beginning of ordered
            FoundNext = True
            Continue While
        End If
     Next
While foundNext
```